# ADF V2 Explicit Mapping

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I need to do some explicit mapping in the Copy Activity and we can't use Flows. Is there a document anywhere that describers how the tabular translator working in the mapping? I need to do some basic expressions in the mapping of the Sink data.

I have googled and can't find anything really on this.
Thanks
Mike

Comment: Please provide some examples of what you need to do.

Comment: what's the source and sink?

Comment: Curious why you can't use mapping data flows for data mapping?

Comment: This is the Government Azure Cloud and unfortunately it doesn't have Data Flows yet...

Comment: i have similar obstacles, in all honest data factory's docs are too superficial to help on real world problems sometimes. I want to use explicit mapping with excel files but somehow the UI won't allow me to specify it(maybe it is not available for excel files) but i can't find any doc that validates if it is possible or not.